# Vakil 3.2.10: Understanding the induced map $\operatorname{Spec} B\to \operatorname{Spec} A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I'm having trouble understanding the following example from Vakil's "The Rising Sea":

> For example, consider a map from the parabola in $\mathbb{C}^2$ (with coordinates $a$ and $b$) given by $b=a^2$, to the "curve" in $\mathbb{C}^3$ (with coordinates $x,\,y$ and $z$) cut out by the equations $y=x^2$ and $z=y^2$. Suppose the map sends the point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ to the point $(a,b,b^2)\in\mathbb{C}^3$. In our new language, we have a map
> $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)\to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-y^2)$ given by $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-y^2)\to\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2),\,(x,y,z)\mapsto(a,b,b^2)$, i.e. $x\mapsto a,\,y\mapsto b$ and $z\mapsto b^2$.

My problem is that $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)$ should only have two "coordinates" and not three, as far as I understand. Where lies my mistake?

Comment: 1. Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: it produces better spacing. 2. Where do you see $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C[a,b]/(b-a^2)$ as having three coordinates? If you're talking about $(x,y,z)\mapsto (a,b,b^2)$ it's explained what that notation is right afterwards: $x\mapsto a$, $y\mapsto b$, and $z\mapsto b^2$.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for the comment, that definitely makes things a little clearer. However: What does the map $x\mapsto a,\, y\mapsto b$ and $z\mapsto b^2$ actually mean in $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)$ in terms of coordinates? So far, it still looks as though $(x,y,z)$ gets mapped to an element that has three coordinates.

Comment: ??? This is a map from the ring $\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-y^2)$ to the ring $\Bbb C[a,b]/(b^2-a)$. Such a map is specified by where it sends $x$, $y$, and $z$. The notation $(x,y,z)\mapsto (a,b,b^2)$ is meant to package up $x\mapsto a$, $y\mapsto b$, $z\mapsto b^2$ in fewer characters, not say anything else. What do you think $(x,y,z)$ means? Because it's not an element of $\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-y^2)$!

Comment: Agree with KReiser. To describe a homomorphism $f$ from $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/I$ to any commutative ring $R$ you need to specify the images $f(x)$, $f(y)$, $f(z)$. Furthermore, they must be chosen in such a way that all of $I$ goes to zero (i.e. $I\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)$).The vector $(a,b,b^2)$ is intended to compactly give the vector $(f(x),f(y),f(z))$.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comments, along with the answer below, have made things clear.

Comment: @KReiser Actually, not quite, there is still one thing I don't understand: We should be able to visualize $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)$ as being (complex) two-dimensional, since $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)$ is, even if we only consider maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)$, that is, the "points" of $\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(b-a^2)$, shouldn't we?

Comment: No, everything you've mentioned in your last comment is (complex) one-dimensional. $(b-a^2)$ is a prime ideal of height one and thus $\Bbb C[a,b]/(b-a^2)$ has dimension one. Please don't ping me again on this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of maps involved in Vakil's example, and I think your confusion stems from the notation seemingly mixing up these two.

The first is a geometrical map, which could be thought of as a function $\overline{\phi}:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^3$, and are specified by three coordinate functions, say $\overline{\phi}_x, \overline{\phi}_y, \overline{\phi}_z: \mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}$, each taking two complex numbers as input and spits out a complex number. Specifically they are $\overline{\phi}_x(a,b) = a$, $\overline{\phi}_y(a,b)=b$, and $\overline{\phi}_z(a,b)=b^2$. Note that this function *does* have three coordinates as you expected.  $\overline{\phi}$ can also be restricted to a map from the curve cut out by $y = x^2$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ to the curve cut out by $y=x^2$ and $z=y^2$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$.

The second is an algebraic map, which is a homomorphism of algebras $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]\to \mathbb{C}[a,b]$. Such maps are specified by the images of the generators $x$, $y$, and $z$. In other words, each polynomial $p(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is mapped to $p(\phi(x),\phi(y),\phi(z))\in\mathbb{C}[a,b]$, where $\phi(x), \phi(y),\phi(z)$ are elements of the ring $\mathbb{C}[a,b]$, in this case the polynomials $a$, $b$, and $b^2$ respectively. To define this map you need to make three specifications, because there are three generators of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, and we don't need to care about the number of generators of $\mathbb{C}[a,b]$. This map also induces a homomorphism of the quotient rings $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-y^2)\to\mathbb{C}[a,b]/(a-b^2)$, because the ideal $(y-x^2, z-y^2)$ gets mapped into the ideal $(a-b^2)$.

I agree that the notation used by Vakil is somewhat confusing. The tuple notation seems at first glance to indicate that somehow elements of $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ or $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y-x^2,z-y^2)$ have "coordinates" $(x,y,z)$, but that is an unfortunate coincidence. The elements of these rings are polynomials in $x$, $y$, and $z$, and the shorthand $(x,y,z)\mapsto (a,b,b^2)$ is only meant to indicate what the image of the generators are. Also notice that the arrow is "going in the wrong direction", so it cannot be interpreted as the desired geometrical map.